# Cannot find ClientTimeoutInterval on HubOptions for SignalR

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

My dotnet core version is 5.0.
I follow [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/th-th/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=dotnet#configure-server-options-1) and still cannot find "ClientTimeoutInterval" property.

[image: Screenshots for my code is here.]

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: That is strange. Can you provide an [mre]? Include your csproj. Also, try ignoring the intelliSense and add it anyway, then see if the build succeeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code below on your .NET 5 with the Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client 5.0.9 package:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSignalR(options =>
    {
        options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(40);
        options.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        options.MaximumParallelInvocationsPerClient = 10;
        options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
        options.StreamBufferCapacity = 50;
        options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    });

    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(CorsSignalrPolicyName, builder => builder
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                .AllowCredentials()
        );
    });
    services.AddControllers();
}
```

The complete example project can be found at https://github.com/hgmauri/signalr-socket-dotnet5